# SQL - joining rows from same table

Tags: sql, join

I only know the bare min when it comes to SQL so please treat me as a complete noob!

I have a table which has many rows but some of them can pair up by the id and I want return array of those rows merged.

```
 post_id  # meta_name # meta_value  #     
======================================
   1      #   bar     #    44       #
   1      #   foo     #    on       #
   2      #   bar     #    1        #
   2      #   foo     #    on       #
   3      #   bar     #    1        #
   3      #   foo     #    off      #
```

as a scaled down version, imagine the above of my table and I am aiming to return 2 results of

```
   1    #   foo    #  bar    #   44   #  on
   2    #   foo    #  bar    #   1    #  on
```

based on that the ids are related and that c2 has the value of 'on'

my attempt was the following from some reading but not getting anywhere

```
SELECT 
    t1.post_id, t2.post_id, t1.meta_name, t2.meta_name, t1.meta_value, t2.meta_value 
FROM 
    `ecom_page_meta` t1 
JOIN 
    `ecom_page_meta` t2 
ON 
    t1.post_id = t2.post_id 
WHERE 
    t1.meta_name = 'featured-products' 
AND 
    t1.meta_value = 'on'
```

any help would be muchly appreciated

** EDIT **

I thought Id just post the syntax which worked nicely below thanks to the answer below:

```
SELECT L.post_id, L.meta_name, R.meta_name, L.meta_value, R.meta_value
FROM `ecom_page_meta` L
INNER JOIN ecom_page_meta R
    ON L.post_id = R.post_id
    AND L.meta_name = 'featured-products-order' 
    AND R.meta_value = 'on' 
WHERE R.meta_name = 'featured-products' 
ORDER BY L.meta_value 
DESC
```

THanks again.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pivot the results from rows into columns based on id. Are you sure you want the c1/c2 values as columns? Will there always be 2 rows of each id? Will only 1 of them ever be on?

Comment: Your table description has C1 & C2, the SQL code, meta_name and meta_value. Please update the table to use the actual names used in the code. Also, `t1.meta_name = 'featured-products'` is a problem, since the sample data does not include that string at all. A complete guess is that you want the last line to be `t2.meta_value = 'on'`.

Comment: sorry I thought that was obvious, I will update. and no they cant be the same row really as they are related to different module settings and results

Comment: You're trying to turn rows into columns. Why would you be trying to do this? It doesn't seem very designer friendly

Comment: @ shred - no, im trying to return both the rows as one if the meta_value is 'on' and the ids match...

Comment: @phil why don't you just create 2 more columns 'meta_type' and 'meta_switch'

Comment: Can we please just stick to the question - another solution would for me  just not to bother, ay?

Comment: You need to redesign the table, as it's not in 3NF. That would solve at least half of your problem by itself. Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @wil is right, this is nota sustainable design. It needs to be redesigned.

Comment: @Phil, the problem is that a poorly designed table will lead to more issues down the road. Your table is in 2NF and has redundant data that is not dependent on the key. You wouldn't have the problem writing the query if it were 3NF.

Comment: _im trying to return both the rows as one if the meta_value is 'on' and the ids match_ The meta_value to which row? You are testing the T1 row against meta_value = 'on', but the sample output you show has the T2.meta_value of 'on' with the test being that T1.meta_value is 'on'

Comment: It is in 3NF if  (post_id, 'meta_name' ) are the primary key, or at least a candidate key. This way of storing stuff is flexible, and very common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create test data:

```
SQL> create table ecom_page_meta (post_id number not null
  2      , meta_name varchar2(15) not null
  3      , meta_value varchar2(15) not null);

Table created.

SQL> insert into ecom_page_meta values (1, 'bar', '44');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ecom_page_meta values (1, 'foo', 'on');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ecom_page_meta values (2, 'bar', '1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ecom_page_meta values (2, 'foo', 'on');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ecom_page_meta values (3, 'bar', '1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ecom_page_meta values (3, 'foo', 'off');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Query to give results matching OP's sample:

```
SQL> select L.post_id, L.meta_name, R.meta_name, L.meta_value, R.meta_value
  2  from ecom_page_meta L
  3  inner join ecom_page_meta R
  4      on L.post_id = R.post_id
  5      and L.meta_value <> 'on'
  6      and R.meta_value = 'on'
  7  where L.meta_name = 'bar';

   POST_ID META_NAME       META_NAME       META_VALUE      META_VALUE
---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
         1 bar             foo             44              on
         2 bar             foo             1               on
```

I still do not know what `WHERE t1.meta_name = 'featured-products'` has do to do with anything since no sample data includes t1.meta_name of the string 'featured-products'.