# How to join rows in some table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, concatenation

i want join some table then concatenation columns

**MyTable**

```
-------------------------------
ID   RowId   LangId   Caption
-------------------------------
1    1       1        ڕۆشتن
2    1       2        Go
3    1       3        اذهب
4    2       1        ئاو
5    2       2        water   
6    2       3        ماء
```

> I want join concatenation **Caption** column ex: for **RowId 1** 'ڕۆشتن - Go - اذهب'

**Desired output**

```
--------------------
RowId   Caption
--------------------
1       ڕۆشتن - Go - اذهب
2       ئاو- water - ماء
```

I seen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422806) but can't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select rowid,
       string_agg(caption, ' ') within group (order by langid) as caption
from t
group by rowid;
```

Comment: Thanks you, i didn’t know about string_agg()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for xml` for older vresion :

```
select r.rowid,
       stuff( (select ' - '+t.caption 
               from table t 
               where t.rowid = r.rowid 
               order by t.LangId
               for xml path('') 
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as Caption
from (select distinct rowid from table ) r;
```

You can use [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for newer version `SQL Server 17+` :

```
select t.rowid,
       string_agg(t.caption, ' ') within group (order by t.langid) as caption
from table t
group by t.rowid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using `for xml` as shown below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.RowId,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ' - ' + t1.[Caption]
         FROM 
         (
           SELECT t.[RowId],
           t2.Caption
           FROM [TestTable] AS t
           INNER JOIN [TestTable] AS t2 ON t2.[RowId] = t.[RowId]
         )
         t1
         WHERE t.RowId = t1.RowId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'') CaptionList
FROM 
(
           SELECT t.[RowId],
           por.Caption
           FROM [TestTable] AS t
           INNER JOIN [TestTable] AS por ON por.RowId = t.RowId
)t;
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c983a361d746a3ac642a215f7cea84f) demo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT DISTINCT RowID,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  Sub.caption +' - '
FROM @tab Sub 
WHERE Sub.rowid = Main.rowid 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Caption
FROM @tab Main

I think this Query can perfectly fit for your case.